# ffmpeg: combine 2 .m2ts files into one mkv/flac file

Tags: ffmpeg, flac, mkv

I'm currently using `ffmpeg -i /mnt/dvd/BDMV/STREAM/00003.m2ts -vcodec copy -c:a flac -ignore_unknown output1.mkv` to backup some Blurays and this has been fine for the smaller discs, but I'm coming across ones with multiple .m2ts files that would be better preserved as one file. is it possible to do this in one command if at all?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming the m2ts files don't have content from multiple programs muxed in, you can run

`ffmpeg -i "concat:/mnt/dvd/BDMV/STREAM/00003.m2ts|/mnt/dvd/BDMV/STREAM/00004.m2ts" -vcodec copy -c:a flac -ignore_unknown output1.mkv`.

Comment: man, I could have sworn I tried this and it didn't work properly. thank you!